# Write a program that prompts the user to enter two characters and displays the major and status represented in the characters

Tags: visual-c++

Details: The first character indicates the major and the second is number character 1, 2, 3, 4, which indicates whether a student is a freshman, sophomore, junior, or senior. Suppose the following characters are used to denote the majors: 
M: Mathematics
C: Computer Science
I: Information Technology

Samples: Enter two characters: M1 (Press Enter)
Result: Mathematics Freshman

Samples: Enter two characters: C3 (Press Enter)
Result: Science Junior

Samples: Enter two characters: T3 (Press Enter)
Result: Invalid Major

Samples: Enter two characters: M8 (Press Enter)
Result: Invalid status code

This is all I have so far. I've already requested help from me instructor. His message is below the code.

```
{

cout << "Enter a two characters (one letter and one number): ";
char major;
int year;
cin >> major;

string major_in, major_out;
string year_in, year_out;

string a = "freshman";
string b = "sophomore";
string c = "junior";
string d = "senior";
string M = "Mathematics";
string C = "Computer Science";
string I = "Information Technology";

if (major_in == "M") major_out == M;
else if (major_in == "C") major_out == C;
else if (major_in == "I") major_out == I;

if (year_in == "1") year_out == a;
else if (year_in == "2") year_out == b;
else if (year_in == "3") year_out == c;
else if (year_in == "4") year_out == d;

cout << major_out << endl;

return 0;

}
```

I think you are thinking too hard about this. You are certainly trying to make it much harder than it actually is. You simply need to input 2 variables (1 char, 1 int) and through a series of if statements determine if they are freshman, sophomore, junior or senior and what the major is. You will need to define a string for the output (Major and Year). If  (major_in == “M”)  major_out ==”Mathematics” ; else if (major_in == “I”) major_out == “Information Technology”; and so on. Do the same thing for the year … if (year_in == 1) year_out == “Freshman”; if(year_in == 2) year_out == “Sophmore” and so on. Once you have the major_out and the year_out just display them together

```
cout<<major_out ” “ year_out<< endl
```

use the “ “ to put a blank space between the major and year in the output. I hope this helps

This kind of helped and didn't help at all, because I lack the understanding of what it is I am doing wrong. I don't know where to start to fix this. I'm getting no 'output' at all. Right now I'm stuck on trying to get "M" to produce... any message at all. I stuck and frustrated. Can someone please guide me through my errors?

This is what I have reduced it to in order to get "Mathematics to appear. I'm stuck. If I'm doing something wrong, someone please tell me what to focus on!!!!

{

```
cout << "Enter a two characters (one letter and one number): ";
char major;
cin >> major;

string major_in, major_out;
string year_in, year_out;

if (major_in == "M") major_out == "Mathematics";
cout << major_out;


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you just don't understand programming. What your professor said is pretty self explanatory. Look up what if statements are. Nobody is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Not asking anyone to do it for me.. I clearly asked if I could be guided through my errors, if you had read it all...

Comment: Where are you outputting the `year_out` variable?

Comment: It's been removed since I cannot get major_in to produce a message, so now I'm trying to get the if statement for major_in to produce "Mathematics"

Comment: Your teacher is telling you that you don't need to use intermediate variables for the output.  You are also assigning your variables incorrectly as noted below.  See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/  You can basically write this program by following what's on that tutorial page.

Comment: "Where are you outputting the year_out variable?"  what do you mean by where?

Comment: That tutorial is based on information that's already there. I don't know how to work "cin" with "if" statements. I need a human with experience. I can't "ask" the text and expect to get an answer from it. I don't have the experience you and others have that's used to break this all down. It's the reason I came here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you got me to write my first ever CPP program with this question I'll let you see some of what I came up with.

```
cout << "Enter a two characters (one letter and one number): ";
char major;
cin >> major;

if (major == 'M')
{
    cout << "Mathematics";
}
else if (major == 'C')
{
    cout << "Computer Science";
}
else if (major == 'I')
{
    cout << "Information Technology";
}
else
{
    cout << "Undefined Major";
}
```

This will get you halfway there.  You should be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, in `(major_in == "M") major_out == M;` you have major_out == M. This is not how you assign data to a variable. It should be major_out = M. Remove the second = sign. Should also change the double quotes into single quotes ('M') since it is a character and not a string of characters.

So, it should now look like : `if(major_in == 'M') major_out = M;`

Make these changes to the rest of the ifs and elses and you should be good.

Comment: I was told that == is important. It's for the use of "else if" if the character does not match.

Comment: the "major_out" portion is the first I'm seeing today because it's not in my textbook and the instructor's e-mail is the first instance I've seen it used.

Comment: == is important when comparing two things which is what you do inside the if statement but you're not assigning M to major_out after you find out major_in is equal to 'M'...

All you need to do is change major_out == M to major_out = M; 

You then can run it and type M1 and based on your current code Mathematics should be output. You will still need to fix the remaining code though.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Enter a two characters (one letter and one number): ";
char major;
int year;
cin >> major;
```

in your first line here you asked for two characters, then in the fourth line you put both characters in the variable major, which isn't valid. you should have asked for the char in one line and set it to major, then asked for the int in another line and set it to year.

Comment: I removed "int year" to focus on getting major to produce the right message, attempting to get it to work.

Comment: An instance of "year" has been removed since I cannot get beyond major.    if (major_in == "M") major_out = M; is a first for me because it's not in the text book. (major_out) has no example in the textbook so today is the first I'm seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class A
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter two character : ");
String s = scan.next();

char ch = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
char n = s.charAt(1);

String coursename="";
String number = "";

if(ch=='M' || ch=='C' || ch=='I')
{

switch(ch)
{   
    case 'M':
    coursename = "Mathematics";
    break;
    
    case 'C':
    coursename = "Computer Science";
    break;
    
    case 'I':
    coursename= "Infomation And Technology";
    break;
    
    default : 
    break;
}

switch(n)
{
    case '1':
    number="Freshman";
    break;
    
    case '2':
    number="Sophomore";
    break;
    
    case '3':
    number="Junior";
    break;
    
    default:
    break;
    
}

System.out.println(coursename+" "+number);
}

else
{
System.out.println("invalid input");
}

}
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: true                                                                                                                                                           thank you for explaining me from now onwards i will try it .